# How to check for presence of a value inside a JSOB objects which in turn has an array for it's value

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

This is the data I have in the jobs table

```
id, title, requirements
1,  software engineer, { qualifications: ["masters", "bachelors"], skills: ["react", "rails"] }
2,  product engineer, { qualifications: ["masters", "associate"], skills: ["trello", "excel"] }
```

Let's say I have candidates table:

```
id, name, resume
1, Mark, { qualifications: "masters", skills: ["react", "rails"] }
2, Temeka, { qualifications: "associate", skills: ["powerpoint", "excel"] }
```

I'm building a query for Mark that will return the jobs that he does NOT have the requirements for, like this:

```rb
where_clause = { qualifications: "masters", skills: ["react", "rails"] }.map do |key, value|
 <<~SQL
  (
    NOT jobs.requirements @> '{"#{key}": ["#{value}"]}'
    OR
    NOT jobs.requirements @> '{"#{key}": "#{value}"}'
  )
  SQL
end
```

I'm doing the above two checks because `value` can either be an array `["react", "rails"]` or it can be just a string `masters`.

It doesn't seem to work. Mark is getting disqualified for job#1 for which has the requirements. What am I doing wrong here?

I believe this is primarily a POSTGRESQL issue I'm having, so don't worry about the ruby code here.

Comment: @Schwern, a_horse_with_no_name, sorry corrected it, you guys are right they are NOT arrays.

Answer (score 1):

To find all jobs that Mark is not qualified for, you can use this:

```
select *
from jobs j
where not exists (select *
                  from candidates c
                  where c.name = 'Mark'
                    and (j.requirements -> 'qualifications') @> (c.resume -> 'qualifications')
                    and (j.requirements -> 'skills') @> (c.resume -> 'skills'))
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0019ac2832f129ec7edb95797aa7be36)

If you want to hardcode the parameters rather then taking them from the table directly, you can do it like this:

```sql
select *
from jobs j
where not (    j.requirements -> 'qualifications' @> '["masters"]'
           and j.requirements -> 'skills' @> '["react", "rails"]')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @a_horse_with_no_name, however, I don't want to use a not exists query. I've just mentioned a simplified model in the question, the real model has many different fields. Perhaps, I should have been more clear, I'm looking to see what is the operator that would return true if a value is inside an array, so that I can negate that (by adding a NOT before it).

Comment: "*that would return true if a value is inside an array,*" that would be `@>` - as you can see in my query. But the  `not exists` is the most efficient way of doing that. What's wrong with it?